# Custom Icon & name in yii2 oAuth client widjet

Tags: oauth-2.0, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to create yii2 oAuth server I need custom icon & name for my client in view

This is the code where we set view

```
 <?php echo yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice::widget([
                    'baseAuthUrl' => ['/user/sign-in/oauth']
                ]) ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow doc: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-authclient-widgets-authchoice.html
You can try:

```
$authAuthChoice->clientLink($client, 'content_of_your_<a>_tag', ['class' => 'class_of_your_<a>_tag'])
```

My example:

```
$authAuthChoice->clientLink($client,
'<span class="fa fa-'.$client->getName().'"></span> Sign in with '.$client->getTitle(),
[
    'class' => 'btn btn-block btn-social btn-'.$client->getName(),
])
```

You can see in:
    - File: vendor/yiisoft/yii/authclient/widgets/AuthChoice.php
    - Line 182: public function clientLink($client, $text = null, array $htmlOptions = [])